# How write your own logging class

Tags: qt, xmpp

Guys I'm suppose to divide by type, for example WARNING and INFO logs ought to be saved in other files... Below is the **QXmpp** library's class **QXmppLogger**, it saves all logging types to one file but I have to make it by my way as I aforementioned. Can anybody direct me through

PS
I **CAN NOT** to change QXmppLogger class!

**QXmppLogger.h**

```
#ifndef QXMPPLOGGER_H
#define QXMPPLOGGER_H

#include <QObject>

#include "QXmppGlobal.h"

#ifdef QXMPP_LOGGABLE_TRACE
#define qxmpp_loggable_trace(x) QString("%1(0x%2) %3").arg(metaObject()->className(), QString::number(reinterpret_cast<qint64>(this), 16), x)
#else
#define qxmpp_loggable_trace(x) (x)
#endif

class QXmppLoggerPrivate;

/// \brief The QXmppLogger class represents a sink for logging messages.
///
/// \ingroup Core

class QXMPP_EXPORT QXmppLogger : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_ENUMS(LoggingType)
    Q_FLAGS(MessageType MessageTypes)
    Q_PROPERTY(QString logFilePath READ logFilePath WRITE setLogFilePath)
    Q_PROPERTY(LoggingType loggingType READ loggingType WRITE setLoggingType)
    Q_PROPERTY(MessageTypes messageTypes READ messageTypes WRITE setMessageTypes)

public:
    /// This enum describes how log message are handled.
    enum LoggingType
    {
        NoLogging = 0,      ///< Log messages are discarded
        FileLogging = 1,    ///< Log messages are written to a file
        StdoutLogging = 2,  ///< Log messages are written to the standard output
        SignalLogging = 4,  ///< Log messages are emitted as a signal
    };

    /// This enum describes a type of log message.
    enum MessageType
    {
        NoMessage = 0,          ///< No message type
        DebugMessage = 1,       ///< Debugging message
        InformationMessage = 2, ///< Informational message
        WarningMessage = 4,     ///< Warning message
        ReceivedMessage = 8,    ///< Message received from server
        SentMessage = 16,       ///< Message sent to server
        AnyMessage = 31,        ///< Any message type
    };
    Q_DECLARE_FLAGS(MessageTypes, MessageType)

    QXmppLogger(QObject *parent = 0);
    ~QXmppLogger();

    static QXmppLogger* getLogger();

    QXmppLogger::LoggingType loggingType();
    void setLoggingType(QXmppLogger::LoggingType type);

    QString logFilePath();
    void setLogFilePath(const QString &path);

    QXmppLogger::MessageTypes messageTypes();
    void setMessageTypes(QXmppLogger::MessageTypes types);

public slots:
    virtual void setGauge(const QString &gauge, double value);
    virtual void updateCounter(const QString &counter, qint64 amount);

    void log(QXmppLogger::MessageType type, const QString& text);
    void reopen();

signals:
    /// This signal is emitted whenever a log message is received.
    void message(QXmppLogger::MessageType type, const QString &text);

private:
    static QXmppLogger* m_logger;
    QXmppLoggerPrivate *d;
};

/// \brief The QXmppLoggable class represents a source of logging messages.
///
/// \ingroup Core

class QXMPP_EXPORT QXmppLoggable : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    QXmppLoggable(QObject *parent = 0);

protected:
    /// \cond
    virtual void childEvent(QChildEvent *event);
    /// \endcond

    /// Logs a debugging message.
    ///
    /// \param message

    void debug(const QString &message)
    {
        emit logMessage(QXmppLogger::DebugMessage, qxmpp_loggable_trace(message));
    }

    /// Logs an informational message.
    ///
    /// \param message

    void info(const QString &message)
    {
        emit logMessage(QXmppLogger::InformationMessage, qxmpp_loggable_trace(message));
    }

    /// Logs a warning message.
    ///
    /// \param message

    void warning(const QString &message)
    {
        emit logMessage(QXmppLogger::WarningMessage, qxmpp_loggable_trace(message));
    }

    /// Logs a received packet.
    ///
    /// \param message

    void logReceived(const QString &message)
    {
        emit logMessage(QXmppLogger::ReceivedMessage, qxmpp_loggable_trace(message));
    }

    /// Logs a sent packet.
    ///
    /// \param message

    void logSent(const QString &message)
    {
        emit logMessage(QXmppLogger::SentMessage, qxmpp_loggable_trace(message));
    }

signals:
    /// Sets the given \a gauge to \a value.
    void setGauge(const QString &gauge, double value);

    /// This signal is emitted to send logging messages.
    void logMessage(QXmppLogger::MessageType type, const QString &msg);

    /// Updates the given \a counter by \a amount.
    void updateCounter(const QString &counter, qint64 amount = 1);
};

Q_DECLARE_OPERATORS_FOR_FLAGS(QXmppLogger::MessageTypes)
   #endif // QXMPPLOGGER_H
```

And here is the **QXmppLogger.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>

#include <QChildEvent>
#include <QDateTime>
#include <QFile>
#include <QMetaType>
#include <QTextStream>

#include "QXmppLogger.h"

QXmppLogger* QXmppLogger::m_logger = 0;

static const char *typeName(QXmppLogger::MessageType type)
{
    switch (type)
    {
    case QXmppLogger::DebugMessage:
        return "DEBUG";
    case QXmppLogger::InformationMessage:
        return "INFO";
    case QXmppLogger::WarningMessage:
        return "WARNING";
    case QXmppLogger::ReceivedMessage:
        return "RECEIVED";
    case QXmppLogger::SentMessage:
        return "SENT";
    default:
        return "";
    }
}

static QString formatted(QXmppLogger::MessageType type, const QString& text)
{
    return QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString() + " " +
        QString::fromLatin1(typeName(type)) + " " +
        text;
}

static void relaySignals(QXmppLoggable *from, QXmppLoggable *to)
{
    QObject::connect(from, SIGNAL(logMessage(QXmppLogger::MessageType,QString)),
                     to, SIGNAL(logMessage(QXmppLogger::MessageType,QString)));
    QObject::connect(from, SIGNAL(setGauge(QString,double)),
                     to, SIGNAL(setGauge(QString,double)));
    QObject::connect(from, SIGNAL(updateCounter(QString,qint64)),
                     to, SIGNAL(updateCounter(QString,qint64)));
}

/// Constructs a new QXmppLoggable.
///
/// \param parent

QXmppLoggable::QXmppLoggable(QObject *parent)
    : QObject(parent)
{
    QXmppLoggable *logParent = qobject_cast<QXmppLoggable*>(parent);
    if (logParent) {
        relaySignals(this, logParent);
    }
}

/// \cond
void QXmppLoggable::childEvent(QChildEvent *event)
{
    QXmppLoggable *child = qobject_cast<QXmppLoggable*>(event->child());
    if (!child)
        return;

    if (event->added()) {
        relaySignals(child, this);
    } else if (event->removed()) {
        disconnect(child, SIGNAL(logMessage(QXmppLogger::MessageType,QString)),
                this, SIGNAL(logMessage(QXmppLogger::MessageType,QString)));
        disconnect(child, SIGNAL(setGauge(QString,double)),
                this, SIGNAL(setGauge(QString,double)));
        disconnect(child, SIGNAL(updateCounter(QString,qint64)),
                this, SIGNAL(updateCounter(QString,qint64)));
    }
}
/// \endcond

class QXmppLoggerPrivate
{
public:
    QXmppLoggerPrivate(QXmppLogger *qq);

    QXmppLogger::LoggingType loggingType;
    QFile *logFile;
    QString logFilePath;
    QXmppLogger::MessageTypes messageTypes;

private:
    QXmppLogger *q;
};

QXmppLoggerPrivate::QXmppLoggerPrivate(QXmppLogger *qq)
    : loggingType(QXmppLogger::NoLogging),
    logFile(0),
    logFilePath("QXmppClientLog.log"),
    messageTypes(QXmppLogger::AnyMessage),
    q(qq)
{
}

/// Constructs a new QXmppLogger.
///
/// \param parent

QXmppLogger::QXmppLogger(QObject *parent)
    : QObject(parent)
{
    d = new QXmppLoggerPrivate(this);

    // make it possible to pass QXmppLogger::MessageType between threads
    qRegisterMetaType< QXmppLogger::MessageType >("QXmppLogger::MessageType");
}

QXmppLogger::~QXmppLogger()
{
    delete d;
}

/// Returns the default logger.
///

QXmppLogger* QXmppLogger::getLogger()
{
    if(!m_logger)
        m_logger = new QXmppLogger();

    return m_logger;
}

/// Returns the handler for logging messages.
///

QXmppLogger::LoggingType QXmppLogger::loggingType()
{
    return d->loggingType;
}

/// Sets the handler for logging messages.
///
/// \param type

void QXmppLogger::setLoggingType(QXmppLogger::LoggingType type)
{
    if (d->loggingType != type) {
        d->loggingType = type;
        reopen();
    }
}

/// Returns the types of messages to log.
///

QXmppLogger::MessageTypes QXmppLogger::messageTypes()
{
    return d->messageTypes;
}

/// Sets the types of messages to log.
///
/// \param types

void QXmppLogger::setMessageTypes(QXmppLogger::MessageTypes types)
{
    d->messageTypes = types;
}

/// Add a logging message.
///
/// \param type
/// \param text

void QXmppLogger::log(QXmppLogger::MessageType type, const QString& text)
{
    // filter messages
    if (!d->messageTypes.testFlag(type))
        return;

    switch(d->loggingType)
    {
    case QXmppLogger::FileLogging:
        if (!d->logFile) {
            d->logFile = new QFile(d->logFilePath);
            d->logFile->open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Append);
        }
        QTextStream(d->logFile) << formatted(type, text) << "\n";
        break;
    case QXmppLogger::StdoutLogging:
        std::cout << qPrintable(formatted(type, text)) << std::endl;
        break;
    case QXmppLogger::SignalLogging:
        emit message(type, text);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}

/// Sets the given \a gauge to \a value.
///
/// NOTE: the base implementation does nothing.

void QXmppLogger::setGauge(const QString &gauge, double value)
{
    Q_UNUSED(gauge);
    Q_UNUSED(value);
}

/// Updates the given \a counter by \a amount.
///
/// NOTE: the base implementation does nothing.

void QXmppLogger::updateCounter(const QString &counter, qint64 amount)
{
    Q_UNUSED(counter);
    Q_UNUSED(amount);
}

/// Returns the path to which logging messages should be written.
///
/// \sa loggingType()

QString QXmppLogger::logFilePath()
{
    return d->logFilePath;
}

/// Sets the path to which logging messages should be written.
///
/// \param path
///
/// \sa setLoggingType()

void QXmppLogger::setLogFilePath(const QString &path)
{
    if (d->logFilePath != path) {
        d->logFilePath = path;
        reopen();
    }
}

/// If logging to a file, causes the file to be re-opened.
///

void QXmppLogger::reopen()
{
    if (d->logFile) {
        delete d->logFile;
        d->logFile = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the `QXmppLogger::SignalLogging` option. If it is set, the object will emit `message(type, text);` signal instead of writing to file. You can connect to this signal and do whatever you want with `type` and `text`.